# How can I check if two large arrays are equal?

Tags: rust

How can I check if 2 `[u8; 256]` arrays are equal (i.e. all elements are the same)? The compiler tells me that `PartialEq` isn't implemented, but if I try to implement it then it tells me the type isn't defined in the crate.

```
fn main() {
    let a1: [u8; 256] = [0; 256];
    let a2: [u8; 256] = [0; 256];

    println!("a1 equals a2 is: {}", a1 == a2);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cd5f6015ca6da7973ec0d334fb987c8f&version=stable)

The output is:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `[u8; 256]`
 --> src/main.rs:5:37
  |
5 |     println!("a1 equals a2 is: {}", a1 == a2);
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `[u8; 256]`
```

This works for smaller sized arrays so it's really confusing me.

Comment: The duplicate applied to your situation: `println!("a1 equals a2 is: {}", &a1[..] == &a2[..]);`